# Where do /root/.bashrc and /root/.profile come from on a Debian system?

Tags: debian, root, bashrc, profile

Normally when you add a user on a Debian system, the contents of `/etc/skel/` are copied into the new user's home directory. But `/root/.bashrc` does not match `/etc/skel/.bashrc` and `/root/.profile` does not match `/etc/skel/.profile`. Also neither file is known to `dpkg`. So where do they come from?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`root`'s files are copied from [`base-files`](https://tracker.debian.org/base-files): if they're missing, its [`postinst`](https://sources.debian.net/src/base-files/13/debian/postinst.in/) copies [`/usr/share/base-files/dot.bashrc`](https://sources.debian.net/src/base-files/13/share/dot.bashrc/) to `/root/.bashrc` and [`/usr/share/base-files/dot.profile`](https://sources.debian.net/src/base-files/13/share/dot.profile/) to `/root/.profile`. Additionally, if `/root/.profile` matches one of the recorded [checksums](https://sources.debian.net/src/base-files/13/share/dot.profile.md5sums/) (which means it hasn't been changed by the administrator), it is updated on upgrade.

The same applies to `/etc/profile` and `/etc/nsswitch.conf` (including updating on upgrade), and `/etc/motd`.