# Why is Debian's default bash shell colourless?

Tags: bash, debian, shell

I have been searching about why the default Debian shell is colourless and couldn't find a answer.

Why is the Debian shell (bash) colourless by default?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Why is the Debian shell (bash) colourless by default?

Because of this (from `.bashrc` on a vanilla Debian install, emphasis mine):

```
# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi
```

In other words, this is "a feature", or a design choice if you will.

Comment: Which is sort of funny because I find it much easier to tell where the output is when the prompt **has** color.

Comment: @chicks Well, at least it is easy to change it into a colourful prompt if one desires!

Comment: I've been pondering for some years reaching the person who dared writing such a fallaciously pedantic, aggressive, pointless, totally arguable, on the border of being illogical, comment in a file that's copied in every user's home.

Comment: @JohanBoulé 100% agree. total wtf to put such opinionated things in widely distributed defaults.

Comment: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=953591

Comment: This change was made by doko in bash 3.2-0ubuntu16. From https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash/+bug/103929, "I don't want to apply this; the focus in a terminal window is not the prompt, but the things what you are doing there. Having this by default turned on in every gnome-terminal and kterm makes me cry."

Comment: Not just the comment reasoning is totally nonsense and an "IMO moment", like @JohanBoulé brilliantly pointed out, it also amuses me how Ubuntu package managers ended up uncommenting the `force_color_prompt=yes` line to default non-root users but still left the bogus "turned off by default" part... 

Answer (score 7):

(The original version of the question suggested it was about root’s shell; I’m leaving this here because it might be useful for users wondering specifically about that.)

In root’s case, the default prompt is colourless because [`/etc/profile`](https://sources.debian.net/src/base-files/9.7/share/profile/) — or rather, `/etc/bash.bashrc` — defines a very simple prompt:

```
# set a fancy prompt (non-color, overwrite the one in /etc/profile)
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

and [`root`’s default `.bashrc`](https://sources.debian.net/src/base-files/9.7/share/dot.bashrc/) doesn’t override it:

```
# Note: PS1 and umask are already set in /etc/profile. You should not
# need this unless you want different defaults for root.
# PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\h:\w\$ '
# umask 022
```

See [Where do /root/.bashrc and /root/.profile come from on a Debian system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/305543/86440) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

Because this was the top result for 'how to colorize root shell in debian' search I am posting my solution here: copy and overwrite `/root/.bashrc` with the `/etc/skel/bashrc` file.

This file is much more robust than the installed for `root` and is also the default used for any new users created on the system.

Below are ls coloring excerpts I've tweaked over the years

```
alias la='LS_COLORS="mh=1;37" ls -A'
alias l='LS_COLORS="mh=1;37" ls -CF'
alias ll='LC_COLLATE=C LS_COLORS="mh=1;37" ls -lA --si --group-directories-first'
```

Comment: I like your idea of putting LC_COLLATE directly in the alias :)

Comment: on a fresh Debian 12 VM, the path for me was `/etc/skel/.bashrc` (note the `.` on the filename)

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up with @daniel-sokolowski suggestion to look at `/etc/skel/.bashrc`.

But important note that according bash documetntation a `[ -z "$PS1" ]` test is common way to distinct interactive shell vs non-interactive.

This way when you add

```bsh
# part from /etc/skel/.bashrc
...
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

you expose `PS1=` for any kind of shell and it may break non-interactive commands like

```
ssh your-server ls -la
bash completion on: scp ssh://foo:/bar/<TAB>
vim scp://your-server//some/file
```

This commands will be broken when unwanted stdout happen from scripts intended to be part of interactive shells only.

This way complete solution is to wrap block in `[ ! -z "$PS1" ]` test

```bsh
...
if [ ! -z "$PS1" ]; then
    if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
        PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
    else
        PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
    fi
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```